# Should background service and UI be one app?

Tags: android

I wan to create an android app which would have two different use-cases:

1. A background service, which would listen to a specific notification.
2. A UI which would present a visual way to present some information fetched from other resources.

**Questions**

should it be an Android APP which would have 1 service module and 1 UI module OR it would be two apps, one service and other UI?

If these are 2 apps then will user have to install 2 different apps from play or one app can complete the installation of the underlying service app?

Comment: Why would you even want to make 2 apps?

Comment: Dont understand why two apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If these are 2 apps then would user has to install 2 different apps from play or one app can complete the installation of the underlying service app

If you have two apps user will always have to install and grant permissions for each one of them individually.

> Shall it should be on Android APP which would have 1 service module and 1 UI module OR it would be two apps, one service and other UI.

Based on your requirements, I don't see why you need two apps.

Comment: hmm interesting, so an android app can have a UI module and a service module. Service module can stay in background and subscribe to notification it is interested in. Thanks